Why are proxy settings not always respected by programs launched from Term?
Why do some programs evade the proxy settings at Settings > Wifi > Details > Proxies? I would expect that a system-wide setting would apply to all traffic. However, I can set the HTTP and HTTPS proxy to a local IP and port, use an off-the-shelf proxy (like Charles), and kick off certain commands that do not appear in Charles.
A really easy one is curl. If you setup an HTTP proxy and then pop into term and do something like
curl https://www.google.com

You will find that traffic does not go through Charles! Instead, you have to explicitly tell curl where the proxy is, e.g.:
ALL_PROXY=http://localhost:8888 curl https://www.google.com

I'm curious what's happening here. Specific questions:

Is there any information about the type of traffic that actually routes through the wifi proxy settings versus traffic that does not?

Is there a way to route all traffic through a local proxy?


Thanks for reading.

Welcome to Ask Different.  We strongly prefer one question per question. Let’s close this for an edit. It needs to be clear how it’s different from the linked question and then we can reopen if needed for new answers.
